# IFrame Memory Leak when adding/removing IFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, memory-leaks, safari, internet-explorer-11

I have the following HTML that can reproduce the issue I'm seeing. As I add/remove IFrames over time the browser is never releasing the IFrame memory. As a result the memory grows and grows overtime which results in degraded performance. I have seen this impact Safari/IE11/Edge quite a bit while Firefox/Chrome handle it better. Does anyone have any tips on how to circumvent the IFrame memory leak?

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
<button onclick="remove()">REMOVE</button>
    <script>
  function add() {
    var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
    ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://somewebsite.com');
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
  }
  function remove() {
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('ifrm'));
  }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got the same problem. Try to change to open new window for IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Try these operations:

1. set the iframe url to blank page, such as "";
2. break your page's refs which may ref to the objects of iframe page;
3. set all objects created by the iframe page to null or undefined.

Operation 2 and 3 are available only if the iframe's page is developed by yourself.

If you did 1 and 2, then the chrome will release the js heap immediately which is allocated by the iframe page.

If you did 1, 2 and 3 then the firefox will release the js heap immediately too.

But, even if you did all the operations above, the Safari won't release the js heap in a period.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this snippet that can help clean the `iframe` before removing it:

```js
(function () {
    var beforeKeys = []
    for (var k in window) {
        beforeKeys.push(k)
    }

    function wipeCreatedKeys() {
        for (var k in window) {
            if (beforeKeys.indexOf(k) !== -1) {
                continue
            }
            window[k] = null
        }
    }

    window.wipeCreatedKeys = wipeCreatedKeys;
})();
```

Add it as soon as possible in your `iframe`, and call `wipeCreatedKeys` before unloading/removing it.

Major performance improvements on Firefox. Chrome doesn't need that, though.